# Puppeteer taking so long to load the page

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to load a URL using Puppeteer and take the screenshot, somehow the page loading is taking too long. Here is my code

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            // headless: false,
            args: [
                `--window-size=42280,39960`,
                // `--shm-size=1gb`,
                // `--disable-dev-shm-usage`
            ]
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({
            height: 39960,
            width: 42280,
        });
        console.log('Page created');
        await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
        console.log('page loaded');
        await page.screenshot({
            path: 'example.png'
        });
        await browser.close();
    })();
```

Did anyone face the same problem?

Comment: On my Win7 x64 machine it just crashes trying to make a screenshot. What is the reason for such high resolution?

Comment: I am just building a prototype and as part of it I need a high-resolution image

Answer (score 3):

The reason of the failure is this:

```
await page.setViewport({
  height: 39960,
  width: 42280,
});
```

> Error running your code. Error: Protocol error
>   (Page.captureScreenshot): Target closed.

Puppeteer can't take a screenshot with that resolution.

Comment: Not sure why it's a problem for Puppeteer. I am just building a prototype and as part of it I need a high resolution image

Comment: I don't think it's a puppeteer issue, mort like Chrome's.